# SQLite returns int instead of real

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm working on a website in node js and use SQLite as a database for the first time.

I want to be able to use real for some form data and I noticed that every real in my database are converted to integer once the query is made.

To vizualize the database i am using DB Browser and i checked if the columns are defined as REAL which they are.

If i try to query a data set as 0.1 in my DB I get this :

```
sqlite> select step_variable 
from variables 
where id=38;

0.0
```

After trying as suggested the command TYPEOF(step_variable) it returned :

```
0.0|real
```

Answer (score 1):

In the SQLite `CREATE TABLE` command, one defines a data type affinity, not a data type. SQLite supports the following five column affinities: `TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL, NONE`.
Thus the data type you specify when creating a table does not enforce a certain data type. You can supply any data type you want or even omit the data type.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
column1 ABC,
column2 Others,
column3 WHATEVER);

CREATE TABLE table2(column1, column2, column3);
```

Populate tables:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 1, 'my text', 123.45);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES( 1, 'my text', 123.45);
```

Now let us check what SQLite made out of it:

```
SELECT column1, TYPEOF(column1) from table1
SELECT column2, TYPEOF(column1) from table1
SELECT column3, TYPEOF(column1) from table1
```

With:

```
column TYPEOF(column)
------------------------
1       INTEGER
my text TEXT
123.45  REAL
```

When you go through a query result e.g. by using sqlite2_step you can use the `sqlite3_column_type` statement to confirm the column type - unless you know the result anyway and simply cast the result to the data type expected.
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it was simply that i didn't save my file after modifying it.